# How to animate drawables with objectAnimator

Tags: android, objectanimator

I want to add a rotating drawable as the `drawableRight` of a button but it's not working. The drawable is showing beside the text of thee button but it's not rotating. This is the code I am trying to use.

```
Drawable loader = ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_rotate_right);

                ObjectAnimator rotateAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(loader,
                        "rotation", 0f, 360f);
                rotateAnim.setDuration(500);
                rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
                rotateAnim.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.RESTART);
                rotateAnim.start();

                simpleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, loader, null);
```

Please do you have  any idea how this can be achieved?

**Note:** The drawable is a vector drawable.

Comment: Have you tried using an AnimatedVectorDrawable instead of using just the ObjectAnimator? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimatedVectorDrawable.html

Comment: @LucasCrawford No I haven't tried.

Comment: You could create your animated vector drawable, then set the drawable as the buttons drawable right in XML, and simply make the drawable start animating via `simpleButton.getCompoundDrawables()[2].start()`

Comment: @LucasCrawford I do not want to set the drawable via xml